# Can I make unlocking the screensaver also unlock the login keychain?

Tags: macos, keychain

I have the screen saver on my Mac password protected, but unlocking the screen saver does not unlock the login keychain.  I know this because I get asked to unlock the login keychain shortly after unlocking the screensaver.

Yes, my login password and keychain password have been synchronized.

Yes, I've run Keychain First Aid and confirmed there are no problems.

The workaround is to change the Keychain Settings so the login keychain never automatically locks, but I'd prefer to have it lock automatically, especially on my laptop when it goes to sleep, but now with Mountain Lion and iCloud that means typing my password twice every time I wake my laptop: once for the screensaver and once for the keychain.

There should be a way to make the screensaver also unlock the keychain just the way the normal login also unlocks the keychain. Is there?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you change your login password without changing your keychain password.

1. Open **Keychain Access**
2. Click **Edit** -> **Change Password for Keychain 'Login'**
3. Match the password to the one you log into the computer with.

If you firmly believe "this is not the problem", please try to delete your keychain and recreate it in order to get the link between the login and keychain to properly function. (thanks @dragon788)

Comment: This is not the problem, as I tried to indicate by saying "Yes, my login password and keychain password have been synchronized."

Comment: This is the most correct answer, but sometimes you actually have to delete your keychain and recreate it in order to get the link between the login and keychain to properly function.

Answer (score -1):

*I have read that you ran Keychain First Aid*,

but you were not clear about checking your "Keychain First Aid" preferences (under Keychain Preferences):  you can choose there to **never lock the keychain while logged in**, and re-run First Aid.

Also, if you right-click on the keychain, which requires a manual unlock, and then choose keychain settings, there is an option to **lock the keychain after x minutes of inactivity** or at system sleep.

My guess is that the first setting might be activated.

Comment: Like I said, "_The workaround is to change the Keychain Settings so the login keychain never automatically locks, but I'd prefer to have it lock automatically_"